# Cannot write to NAS but was previously able to

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions, nas, file-permissions

I have been unable to write to my NAS recently. When I go to save a file to one of the folders I get the message "you dont have permission to save to this location" .   I can see all the folders and files on the NAS ok.   When I go to check the permissions on a folder -- Properties - Security, I see that the groups listed are Everyone, guest and anyone.   But only the "Special Permissions" box is checked.

Easy to fix you might think. Edit permissions and click on Full Control. Click on OK.  BUT  I get a message box.   Error Applying Security.  An error occurred while applying security information to \NAS\public   Access is denied.

This has been driving me nuts because previously I had been using the NAS to back up everything using Acronis, but now Acronis doesn't back up and I can't even save a small text file.

I have tried disabling Homegroup
I have tried Taking Full Control for the application being used. 
and lots of other stuff.   All without successs.

Setup:
Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit PC
NAS is a Agestar 1TB running Fat32. 
Also another Win 7 PC on the home network.

I am a very experienced user but this has beat me.

Thanks for all replies.

Muzz

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your NAS administration application and see if something has changed on the NAS that forced it into read-only mode.  Perhaps there is a setting that makes the drive read-only, or there may be a user-id setting on the NAS for the shared folders that is preventing access.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I have checked all that as NAS administrator. All users have Full Access.